# Is greeting view and the result view pointing to the same object?

Tags: spring, model, request

Here our controller may return one of two views.
In such a case where these 2 method signatures both contained Model Model Map and ModelAttribute, do the views share access to the Model and ModelAttribute loaded by a previous request handle?

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", new Greeting());
        return "greeting";
    }
@PostMapping("/greeting")
public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting greeting) {
    return "result";
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not point the same object.

I am assuming you are using https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/ 
and its code naming convention is quite confusing.

Please see the following **test code**. 
I changed URL, variable name purposely.

Greeting.java

```
public class Greeting {

    private long id;
    private String content;    
    //... getters and setters
}
```

Greeting2.java

```
//created for testing
public class Greeting2 {

    private long id;
    private String content;
    //... getters and setters
}
```

GreetingController.java

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting") // greeting URL and GET request method
    public String greetingForm(Model model) { 
        //  th:object="${foo}" in template and thymeleaf
        model.addAttribute("foo", new Greeting()); 
        return "greeting_tmpl"; // src/main/resources/templates/greeting_tmpl.html
    }

    @PostMapping("/greeting_post")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute Greeting2 bar) {
        //I expected using bar variable in result_tmpl, but it used Greeting2(lowercase) as variable
        return "result_tmpl"; // src/main/resources/templates/result_tmpl.html
    }

}
```

src/main/resources/templates/greeting_tmpl.html

```
...
<body>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting_post}" th:object="${foo}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" /></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text" th:field="*{content}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

src/main/resources/templates/result_tmpl.html

```
...
<body>
    <h1>Result</h1>
    <p th:text="'id: ' + ${greeting2.id}" /> <!-- this name should be like bar.id not greeting2 -->
    <p th:text="'content: ' + ${greeting2.content}" />
    <a href="/greeting">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Simply,

1. Browser triggers @GetMapping.
2. Server Parses Greeting model to HTML form values in greeting template and response to the browser.
3. Submit Form Data using POST method triggers @PostMapping.
4. @ModelAttribute Greeting2(Can be any model which can parse form values(in this case, id,content) will parse form values to Greeting2 model.
5. Server Parses Greeting2 model to HTML form values in greeting template and response to the browser.